# How to fix a ruined recovery mode of an Android device?

Tags: boot, recovery-mode, root-access

It seems like I ruined the recovery mode of my Android tablet. It's a HP Pro Slate 12 tablet with Android 5.1.1 on it. It's rooted. I wanted to install CWM Recovery to backup everything, but my device wasn't listed as a supported device. My friend told me I can install the LG G3 recovery instead because it's compatible. I installed that. Since then recovery mode completely disappeared. The device still boots in normal mode and works, but I cannot boot into recovery mode anymore. I really need it because the device boots normally but sometimes acting strange since I rooted it. I'd like to try unrooting it by going into recovery mode or doing a factory reset, but both options disappeared.

- I tried holding down volume up+power buttons while turning it on, but didn't work.
- Tried holding down volume down+power. Nope.
- Tried rebooting inside Android into recovery mode with Quick boot app. It rebooted my device but again it went into normal mode instead.
- Tried to reboot into recovery mode with ADP and FastBoot in Windows. Same stuff happened. The device rebooted into normal mode.
- Tried to make a factory reset. DIDN'T work! Rebooted into normal mode once more. The factory reset hasn't deleted anything.

Any ideas? Did I lose the possibility of recovery forever with a single click?

Comment: You need flash stock recovery, then find any compatible cwm / twrp and then flash it.

Comment: I cannot do that. There is NO compatible CWM or TWRP recovery for my device. (it's not listed as a supported device) This is why I tried a so called "compatible" one which seems like it has ruined my device forever.

Comment: Ok , but you can find stock recovery. If yes then flash it.

Comment: I only found the latest update.zip for my device on the official website. I found nothing else. That's a zip file, not an img. I cannot use the update.zip without going into recovery mode.  :-(

Comment: Qualcomm devices usually have a workaround to flash entire internal partitions like with Oneplus 3 http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-3/how-to/guide-mega-unbrick-guide-hard-bricked-t3405700 Similarly search if Unbrick Guides are available for HP Pro Slate 12. Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

with ADB con your PC install the TWRP recovery and then with the comand "adb reboot recovery" the phone enter in recovery mode

Answer (score 0):

If you have the official update package (a zip, usually), open it in an archive viewer and extract **recovery.img**. **That's the stock recovery.** Boot into bootloader (aka fastboot) and use the command line tool `fastboot` to flash it.

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

As simple as instructed above.

Comment: fastboot flash was successful, but the device still does not boot to recovery. What's the next step?